# My React function not working while page refresh or page change but its working in live server when I change something in code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

My React function not working while page refresh or page change but its working in live server when I change something in code

getRoModul function is not working on page change
my code

```
const getRoModul = async () => {
        const url = "http://localhost:9001/roModels";
        await axios
            .get(url)
            .then((response) => setModels(response.data.response))
            .then(()=>console.log(models))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

    }
useEffect(() => {

    if (id) {
        getSingleCustomer(id);
    }
    getRoModul();

}, [id]);


// single customer

const getSingleCustomer = async (id) => {
    const url = "http://localhost:9001/singlecustomer/" + id;
    fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(resp => {
            if (resp.status === 200) {
                // console.log(resp.response[0])
                setName(resp.response[0].name);
                setEmail(resp.response[0].email);
                setPhone(resp.response[0].phone);
                setAddress(resp.response[0].address);
                setRoModel(resp.response[0].romodel);
            }
        }
        )
}
```

Comment: Your dev server might me running in port 3000 and your ajax call is to port 9001. These are considered 2 different domains. Could be a [CORS issue](https://www.contentstack.com/docs/developers/how-to-guides/understanding-and-resolving-cors-error/)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't working. "...it's not working" isn't very useful to those trying to help. Are there any errors? What is the observed behavior vs the expected behavior?

Comment: No, There has not any CORS issue if I change something in code and save the code then live server working properly and show array in console but when i refresh page it shows no result in console

Comment: What exactly is showing in the console? Manual console logs from your code? Can you edit to share the complete [mcve] you are using?

Comment: My problem is Solved now. I just took a mistake while defining useState, Thanks for your help